# Painting faces on Purim

Tags: halacha, minhag, purim, megillat-esther

I used to see people in a few places have a custom to paint (decorate) their faces on Purim. They explain it as because Hashem hid himself in the whole occasion of the story of purim and the meggilah itself, it is a custom to decorate faces and hide oneself as Hashem did. I heard from a shiur by a person who said that it is not a custom for sephardim.

Is there any sephardic posek that goes against the minhag?

Comment: Probably. There are some poskim that go against dressing up on Purim altogether.

Comment: The question is not about dressing up but painting

Comment: Painting the face would fall under the same category.

Comment: How would that be?